# Is RASTERSTATS compatible with python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x

Rasterstats library (computes statistic on raster file/object) is only compatible with python 2.7 to 3.6 according to [setup.py](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/blob/master/setup.py)

But in fact, according to my experience, it's compatible with python 3.7

Does anybody knows if it's compatible with python 3.8 also ?

Answer (score 0):

Rasterstats was updated 2 hours prior to your question being asked here to formally declare support for Python 3.6 thru 3.9.

See commit [aa4130e2ea03c9227b6793b7fe94adb9485bcb58](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/commit/aa4130e2ea03c9227b6793b7fe94adb9485bcb58), which resolved [Issue 240](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/issues/240).